# my minecraft mouse doesn't drag the items. How do i fix it?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, mouse

The mouse keeps hold of the items/stacks and doesn't drag or place them in the crafting tables.

It's impossible to play like this, and I've checked the controls and keybindings, they're normal.

Please help

Comment: did you click them down, one click to pick them up; one to put them down

Comment: Is this a deviation from normal play or are you new to minecraft? I can't tell whether the controls are just non-intuitive to you or whether there is actually a bug here. In the case of a bug, have you tried turning it off and back on again?

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is that you are holding a whole stack, rather than holding an individual block. To get one individual block, first **LEFT CLICK** on the stack, the **RIGHT CLICK** on an empty area to get an individual block. You can use this for crafting

**TIP**:
If you keep right-clicking, you keep adding to that new stack by one, so you can make a specific stack of 10, by right-clicking ten times

Comment: To move it to the crafting table, simply left-click on the block/stack, then left-click on an empty space in the crafting table.

Comment: It's hard to tell from the question whether the OP doesn't understand the controls or whether they are suffering a glitch/bug. In the latter case your answer is just an irrelevant tutorial so it might have been worthwhile waiting until the OP clarified their problem before answering.

Comment: That is true @Aiken.

Comment: It's also possible that they don't understand how to drag a stack of items over the crafting interface and have it deposit the items as they do so.

Comment: I just love it when someone asks a vague question and disappears. I mean, I really, really, love it. As in, I live for these moments.